# How can I create a new file using Unix command in terminal?

Tags: unix

I want to create a new File Under

> `is/log directory`

in linux.

```
What is the unix command to create a new file ? I am using a putty Terminal .
```

Comment: Did you check this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159672/how-to-create-a-simple-txt-text-file-using-terminal

Comment: Hmm yes. But i didn't get anything from that post. @thebenman .

Comment: @Saravanan because you didn't read it... Pretty clear that solutions are inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably thinking of `touch`.  So, if I just want to create a new file in some path:

```
$touch dir/subdir/foo.txt
```

If you're a Bourne purist, you could use:

```
true > dir/subdir/foo.txt
```

This uses `true`, a regular built-in of the shell like a no-op to redirect stdout to a file which implicitly creates the file.